# How to implement a .Net control with multiple synchronized charts by TeeChart

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

I want to implement a .Net control by TeeChart like this:
1. The control contains multiple charts, all of which share the comman vertical Axis. If one chart is zoomed, the others should be zoomed synchronizedly;
2. Each chart contains multiple horiz lines, each of which corresponds to a unique horizontal Axis.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the example in the features demo at `All Features\Welcome !\Axes\Opaque zones`. The features demo is a program shipped with the TeeChart installation including examples of the main features supported by the component.

If what you have are several `TChart`s and you want to synchronize them, you can handle the `Scroll` events on both chart for it. Ie:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  CreateChart();
  InitializeChart();
}

Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1, tChart2;
private void CreateChart()
{
  tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
  this.Controls.Add(tChart1);

  tChart2 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
  this.Controls.Add(tChart2);

  tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
  tChart2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
}

private void InitializeChart()
{
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart2.Aspect.View3D = false;
  Line line1 = new Line(tChart1.Chart);
  line1.FillSampleValues();
  Line line2 = new Line(tChart2.Chart);
  line2.DataSource = line1;

  tChart1.Scroll += new EventHandler(tChart1_Scroll);
  tChart2.Scroll += new EventHandler(tChart2_Scroll);
}

void tChart1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tChart2.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(tChart1.Axes.Left.Minimum, tChart1.Axes.Left.Maximum);
  tChart2.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum, tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum);
}

void tChart2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tChart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(tChart2.Axes.Left.Minimum, tChart2.Axes.Left.Maximum);
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(tChart2.Axes.Bottom.Minimum, tChart2.Axes.Bottom.Maximum);
}
```